# Trying to make code changes to DockHub image uploaded to Azure Functions

Tags: docker

I have a Docker image as a private repo in DockHub which is in turn hosted in an Azure Function. Everything works well but we have a need to make minor refactors to the the code within. How can I push/update the image with the code changes so that Azure Functions will pick it up?

Did a docker push /:latest and Docker desktop seems to have accepted the pull, however there are none of the code changes done in the new image.

Answer (score 1):

It was not immediately obvious but the dist dir needs to be updated before pushed to a container and in turn to Azure.